# Net field in a conductor subjected to an almost infinitely strong electric field

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

Suppose a spherical conductor with a finite number of charges and a diameter of some finite magnitude is subject to a field that is almost infinitely large in magnitude. With the charges redistributed in layers of negative and positive charges, how would the conducter ever be able to create a field that is also infinitely large in the opposite direction to maintain net field 0 inside the conductor?

I did ask GPT which insisted that the conductor would create a field of exactly the same magnitude in the opposite direction.

Comment: Why should the net field inside be zero in the presence of an external field? Is the net field inside a wire zero when the wire is connected to a voltage source?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I thought that the voltage source maintains a non zero potential difference to keep the charges in motion. In a conductor that is not bound to a voltage source, the charges distribute to create a opposite field with potential inside the conductor being the same as surface.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal conductor is an idealization.  We assume that it has an effectively infinite amount of free charge, such that it can cancel out an external electric field of any magnitude.

Of course, such a material does not actually exist in the real world.  A real piece of metal does in fact have a finite amount of charge, and so there will be a limit to the amount of electric field it can cancel out.

This is one of many approximations & idealizations that you will need to make in physics as your career progresses.  It is worth keeping in mind that such approximations are not strictly true, but you should also remember that they are useful for illustrating general principles; don't let their inaccuracies make you think they're unimportant.

Finally, two side points concerning your question:

- "Almost infinitely large" is not a very meaningful way of describing things. If something is "almost infinite" then it is not actually "infinite", which means that it is finite.
- Don't trust GPT for physics questions.  All too often it spits out answers that are either misleading or out-and-out wrong.

Comment: So the conductor after some point would have to behave like a dielectric?

Comment: @Nahapana  Possibly, but also it would be subject to things like [field emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission) or [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge), neither of which we consider for an "ideal" conductor.